# How do I start using the RAWG api using rawgpy?

Tags: python, api

I'd like to make a database of all the games I play with their developers/publishers/platforms/etc... And I am sure that the RAWG api is the way to do that.
I'm experienced with python but I've never used an API before, here is the code I used from the quickstart guide:

```
import rawgpy
rawg = rawgpy.RAWG("User-Agent, this should identify your app")
results = rawg.search("Warframe")  # defaults to returning the top 5 results
game = results[0]
game.populate()  # get additional info for the game

print(game.name)

print(game.description)

for store in game.stores:
    print(store.url)

rawg.login("someemail@example.com", "somepassword")

me = rawg.current_user()

print(me.name) # print my name, equivalent to print(self.username)

me.populate() # gets additional info for the user

for game in me.playing:
    print(game.name) # prints all the games i'm currently playing
```

However I don't know what to use as my user agent in the second line. Any help would be much appreciated.
[Here is the link to the quickstart guide](https://rawgpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to tell from their documentation, but typically this means you just need to put in a user agent that shows the API your an app calling their api. Lots of APIs block default user agents to prevent spam and abuse, hence the requirement.

So you could literally put:

```
rawg = rawgpy.RAWG("My first app")
```

However it's better practice to put something unique and descriptive that describes your app. For your use case this could be "game-database-app-01".

There probably aren't any syntax requirements on what you can put in, but I wouldn't be surprised if they only accept alphanumeric entries.

It's probably a good idea to always call the same API with the same app name to avoid throwing any errors their end.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It looks like this part of the code is working now, however the line 3 (results = rawg.search("Warframe") ) this returns an empty list instead of the top results for searching "Warframe".  Any idea why this search doesn't work?

Comment: I would try logging in first to see if that helps? Even though it says in their documentation that you should be able to get results without authenticating. Frankly though it looks their API sample code doesn't work as advertised to me. I would try to get an API key from their site (https://rawg.io/apidocs) and then call the API with requests.